# How can i get a date of android device opening time?

Tags: java, android, device

I was wondering that how can i programmatically get a date of android device service opened time and date of the first access to network on the device?

Is it possible?

plz help me...

Comment: @SilentKiller not possible, but why??

Comment: @Nabin thats the thing i am searching. as i dont think so android store it some where. when i inserted my SimCard first time or connect WiFi first time.

Comment: @SilentKiller Please refer to my update in answer

Comment: @Gagamel please elaborate your question more what you exactly you want.

Comment: @Gagamel please refer to my updates in answer

Answer (score 0):

how would users get this application?? the only thing that i can think of is an application that tests connectivity to a known proxy server or something with an ip that doesn't change, however unless you put an apk on an sd card and install the application before activating the device it would only let you know how long that application has been installed on the phone. The best thing to do is call your service provider and ask... if you are doing it from a LAN prospective just keep a list of mac addresses and look at the file modification date. it may help if you explain what it is that you are trying to accomplish, with what you have it is hard to imagine what this application could possibly be used for.

Comment: Isn't there any way to get it programmatically?

Comment: from which? the LAN side or on the device?

Comment: if from the device, you have your answer above.

Comment: what is the file you said?